# Python SQLlite3 execute command not writing values

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x

When I try to run the program, it comes up with the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\documents\GCSE\Computing\Python Files\Databases\Database 1.py", line 15, in <module>
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (first_name,last_name,number,date,order_value)''')
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: first_name
```

The code is as follows, any help that could be given would be appreciated ;D

```
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE Orders4 (customer_first_name text,customer_second_name text,order_number text,order_date date,order_contents text)''')
first_name = input("What is the customer's first name: ")
last_name = input("What is the customer's last name: ")
number = input("What is the order number: ")
order_value = input("What is the order: ")
date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO Orders VALUES(first_name,last_name,number,date,order_value)''')
```

Comment: You call the table `Orders4` when you create it, then try to reference it as `Orders`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there is a typo in your SQL statements (*Orders* vs. *Orders4*).
The actual problem, however, is in the string where you define your `INSERT` command (last line).
If you want the variables `first_name`, `last_name`, etc to be evaluated (i.e. their actual values ending up in the string) you have to [**format**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) the string accordingly. Currently, they are simple strings.

When the database executes the `INSERT` command it sees the word `first_name` and evaluates it as a reference to the column "first_name", which doesn't exist.

If you would quote the variables like so

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO Orders VALUES("first_name","last_name","number","date","order_value")''')
```

the command would work, but you would end up with the actual words "first_name" in the row in your database.

Read about string formatting in the above link and try the following

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO Orders VALUES({fn},{ln},{nr},{dt},{ov})'''.format(fn=first_name,ln=last_name,nr=number,dt=date,ov=over_value))
```

hth, Denis